# Where to put a long transcript of an image?

Tags: seo, images

I am making a comic web site. Each comic is a single png and has a html page. For each comic I have a transcript, like this:

> A and B are sitting on a bench in the park.
>
> A: Nice weather today.
>
> B gives him a weird look: Too rainy!
>
> A: ...

Where I should put that transcript in the html?

`<meta name="description" content="transcript"/>` seemed like a good place, but it seems limited to 155 characters, and my transcripts may be longer than that (up to 900 characters).

The `<img>`'s `alt` attribute might work, but that could be limited in length as well.

I could add it to the page in an invisible `div` with `style="display: none"` (like [old XKCD comics](https://www.xkcd.com/659/) do) but I don't want to have search engines think I am trying to cheat with invisible text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `alt` attribute in such cases is not ideal, because often some markup/structure is needed to describe the image’s content, which `alt` does not allow (it can only contain plain text).

Other options:

- The [`longdesc` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-longdesc-20150226/) allows you to link to a page (or an element on the same page) that contains the "long text description" of an image:

  ```html
  <img src="image.png" alt="…" longdesc="#transcript" />
  ```
- The [`object` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element) can have fallback content in case the image can’t be accessed:

  ```html
  <object data="image.png" type="image/png">
    <!-- … -->
  </object>
  ```
- The [`figure` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) can have a [`figcaption` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element):

  ```html
  <figure>
    <img src="image.png" alt="…" />
    <figcaption>…</figcaption>
  </figure>
  ```

For accessibility, it would be best to provide the transcript for everyone, not only for screen reader users. Many users that could benefit from a transcript don’t use a screen reader, so visually hidden content is really hidden to them.
For the same reason, relying on `alt` or using an `object` element isn’t ideal either, and if `longdesc` gets used, you should also add a hyperlink for users that don’t use a user agent with `longdesc` support.

So ideally you would simply show the transcript on the same page (or another page, and link to it). If using `figure`+`figcaption`, the relationship is clear; otherwise use `longdesc` to connect the `img` with the transcript (and provide a hyperlink if it’s on a different page or not next to the `img`).

Comment: i'm afraid, from SEO point of view it would have contra-productive effect, because of lack of any meaningful machine-readable relation between image, webpage and image description, which is needful to make the page findable in web and image search

Answer (score 1):

if you place it for your human readers, so make it just like usual html, h1+div/p with text.

to prepare it for search engines i see some possibilities:

- primarily i would make use of Exif/IPTC image meta. The caption / abstract is limited to 2.000 characters
- Then i would markup the page with structured markup of Schema.org (mainEntityOfPage -> ImageObject). There are no length limitations, and https://schema.org/ImageObject allows implementation of Exif/IPTC data as property-value pairs.